# how to configure java ENV variable in Azure App Services java11 tomcat 9 stack

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have a java-11 tomcat-9 stack app service. I want to setup xmx (max heap memory) to that.

How can I set that?

Sidepoints

- I went to ssh and tried `printenv | grep JAVA` but I could not find anything. However it prints following line in logs, that means it is taking it from somewhere but not printing it. Am I looking at wrong place?

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMEDPicked up 
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4878M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar
```

- Also, if I set, I need to make sure the default things (like javaagent) does not get overriten otherwise I would lose out other default necessary things (like app insights)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently just put
`JAVA_OPTS` `-Xmx10G` and you are done, it does not override the original variables.